# In selenium python how do I get a value that has been input into a drop down list for comparison later?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am automating a test for a library system. There is a list of books that is displayed on the homepage. When the user adds a library book via a web form, a check then needs to be made whether what was entered is the same as what is displayed in the homepage book list.

I have created some code that will enter a book name and check the output book name, but now I need it to check a value from a drop down list. How do I get a value from a drop down list and then compare it with the record that is output in the homepage books list?

Comment: If it's a <SELECT> element, this will be helpful: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/